# How do I fix infill support in Cura?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, infill

I am making this [dog feeder](https://cad.onshape.com/documents/97c0bff4438703fb46eab336/w/f9d9fd6b8648b1738356fc17/e/875b5b62d7deed4076b9d8c3?renderMode=0&uiState=615b591d20bf03323f3e1f55).

My goal is to 3D print it using an Ender 3 V2. I am using Cura to slice it.

When I slice it, though, Cura does not see the Top part (Dispenser box) as a solid piece. And when I am slicing it, it does not create an infill for the ramp. I have tried using the infill support option and setting the infill overhang angle to 0, but it still does not create infill support on the ramp. Here are some prints:

[image: Notice that there is no infill under the ramp#1]

[image: Notice that there is no infill under the ramp#2]

Notice that there is no infill under the ramp.

How do I make Cura understand that this is a solid piece?

Comment: I'm not an expert at this and maybe someone else will have better insights, but it seems that you did not build it as a solid piece.

Comment: I'm also no expert but you can use Meshmixer to make it a solid or import it into Blender and apply a solidify modifier to the mesh.

Comment: Is that a set in Cura that could fix this?

Comment: Unrelated - consider that your plastic might not be food-safe.

Comment: It is standard PLA. How do I find this out?

Comment: @user3347814 "Another major concern about PLA being food safe is the tiny holes and cracks that are usually created during 3D printing. These holes and cracks can provide a place for the harmful germs and ground for bacteria to grow and can be quite dangerous in the future." Plus another couple points at https://3dmonstr.com/is-pla-food-safe/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've followed the link in the question and exported the dispenser box and sliced it in Ultimaker Cura 4.12.1 and it will slice just fine.

[image]

---

*From a comment on the answer from the OP I've learned later that the model has been fixed. So the issue was related to the model/STL file, not an issue with Cura.*

Comment: That is because I've fixed the problem in the project. I've awarded the right answer for the effort.